# Avoid duplicates in numeric vector shifting numbers

Tags: r, duplicates, numeric

I'm looking for the optimal way to go from a numeric vector containing duplicate entries, like this one:

```
a=c(1,3,4,4,4,5,7,9,27,28,28,30,42,43)
```

to this one, avoiding the duplicates by shifting +1 if appropriate:

```
b=c(1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,27,28,29,30,42,43)
```

side to side comparison:

```
> data.frame(a=a, b=b)
    a  b
1   1  1
2   3  3
3   4  4
4   4  5
5   4  6
6   5  7
7   7  8
8   9  9
9  27 27
10 28 28
11 28 29
12 30 30
13 42 42
14 43 43
```

is there any easy and quick way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: In entry 6 and 7, why did those values change?

Comment: Cause they would otherwise be duplicates after the changes in the previous entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want it to be done only once (there may still be duplicates):

```
a=c(1,3,4,4,4,5,7,9,27,28,28,30,42,43)
a <- ifelse(duplicated(a),a+1,a)
```

output:

```
> a
 [1]  1  3  4  5  5  5  7  9 27 28 29 30 42 43
```

Loop that will lead to a state without any duplicates:

```
a=c(1,3,4,4,4,5,7,9,27,28,28,30,42,43)
while(length(a[duplicated(a)])) {
  a <- ifelse(duplicated(a),a+1,a)
}
```

output:

```
> a
 [1]  1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 27 28 29 30 42 43
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use a recursive function:

```
no_dupes <- function(x) {
  if (anyDuplicated(x) == 0)
    x
  else
    no_dupes(x + duplicated(x))
}

no_dupes(a)
 [1]  1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 27 28 29 30 42 43
```

Answer (score 1):

A tidyverse option using `purrr::accumulate`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

accumulate(a, ~ if_else(.y <= .x, .x+1, .y))

# [1]  1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 27 28 29 30 42 43
```